# What are the side effects of using IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag?

Tags: delphi

What are the side effects of using IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag (to use more than 2GB of RAM) in my program?

I am using Delphi 7 with FastMM4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make sure you don't use the built-in memory manager and use something that can support addresses >2GB. e.g. FastMM.

You may have other code, typically 3rd party code, in your codebase that will fall foul of addresses >2GB. I personally deal with this by running under 64 bit Windows and forcing the system to use [top-down memory allocation via a registry setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190527.aspx).

When you do this you may run into some bugs in Windows. For example [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Vista fails when the address of its parameter is >2GB. I work around that by patching Windows.GetCursorPos with a version that goes through [GetCursorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648389%28VS.85%29.aspx). This bug is fixed in Windows 7 but MS elected not to back-port it to Vista.

I can't stress enough how important it is to run with top-down memory allocation enabled.

Comment: @Yuhong Thanks for that. I did not know that hotfix existed.

Comment: «I can't stress enough how important it is to run with top-down memory allocation enabled.» Can you explain why this is important?

Comment: Because then you will flush out bugs where the developer assumed pointers could not go above 2gb very quickly.

Comment: Ok. It makes sense. Thanks David.

Comment: FYI, after setting the registry key for top-down memory allocation and rebooting my computer, VirtualBox would not load and throw an exception. So I deleted the registry key and rebooted my computer.

Comment: Don't know if it is related though. VirtualBox being a 64-bit app, it should not get in trouble ...

Comment: That's not uncommon. Still loads of programs can't handle this.